# Using Swift Playgrounds to read a file from a user path

Tags: swift, file, download

I have downloaded a file using my iPad into the user Downloads folder, not in the resource bundle for the Playground [footnote].

Is there any way to read it using a Playground? I’ve tried a whole bunch of different things and nothing seems able to access the file.

Here’s an example of what doesn’t work for me:

`// Playground to analyze my finances downloaded from my bank
import SwiftUI;
import Foundation;

// Read in transactions
var filename = "filename.txt"

do {
    print("Letting dir")
    let dir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false);
    print("Dir set, appending file")
    var fileurl = dir.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    
    print("Letting contents of file \( fileurl )");
    let contents = try String(contentsOf: fileurl, encoding: .utf8)
    
    // Process Transactions
    print(contents)
    
    // Display results
    
}
catch {
    print("Error opening file: \( error )")
}`

I think the problem is that it’s accessing the downloads folder of the resources bundle, instead of the system bundle, but I don’t know how to fix that or if it even can be done.

Thanks for any help. This has been unbelievably frustrating and it’s the very first step of my project.

David

[footnote] I can’t even figure out how to access the resource bundle - all the GUI lets me do is edit the Playground code.  And I understand the resource paths frequently change, so that doesn’t seem like the right thing to do anyway.